# How to convert HashSet<&String> to HashSet<String>?

Tags: rust

When I execute this part of my code I get an error. I know I must convert the value, but how?

The code:

```
let cleaned_vec:HashSet<_> = new_file_vec.difference(&new_file_vec2).collect();
new_file_vec=cleaned_vec.clone();
```

The error:

```
   |         new_file_vec=cleaned_vec.clone();
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::collections::HashSet<std::string::String>`
              found struct `std::collections::HashSet<&std::string::String>`
```

Answer (score 0):

`clone` just clones the references inside. You're actually transforming the data, so you should get an iterator, map the clone, then collect back into a `HashSet`:

```rust
let owned_set: HashSet<String> = borrowed_set.iter().map(|&x| x.clone()).collect();
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f0593cc7021fab2fef9000c611d604d)